# How did they make the LEGO Batman cutscenes?

Tags: animation

I want to know what programs they used to make the videos the old LEGO video games like the 2008 LEGO Batman, 2007 Lego Star Wars, and maybe the 2011 LEGO Star Wars for a little modern-ish feel. I want to learn how they made the models, textures, effects, map and etc.

I've just been inspired to make my own LEGO animations. What programs should I use to start?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't work for The LEGO Group or have inside knowledge of how the movies are made.

Comment: See also the answers to [What software was used to create The LEGO Movie](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/3020/56).

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Bricks EggsinaBlender. Teaching you how to use 3d software is rather beyond the scope of this site, or indeed a single question and answer here - you might be better off taking a look at some of the great tutorials for [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) (a popular open source 3D modelling application). You can also find some [helpful guides](https://youtu.be/7FNUxEfvd48) to exporting models from LEGO Digital Designer or Stud.IO to LDraw format and then into a format that other programs can use.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely Autodesk Maya and possibly some other tools based on LEGO internal parts libraries like the Easy Builder Tool or Brick Builder.

All of those games are made by [Traveller's Tales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveller%27s_Tales). In a video on the development process for their Jurassic Park title you will see that they use Maya to create and animate their models (the right screen would be very familiar looking to a Maya user).

[image: frame of video showing 2 monitors]

More-than-likely this is the same software they use to animate their cutscenes, and I doubt they have changed software packages since then.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good little write up from Animal Logic, who made the Lego Movie, Lego Batman Movie, etc:

https://www.animallogic.com/portfolio/projects/tlm/

A lot of it is custom built for them and they don't reveal the secrets.

This little bit is pretty good as well:

https://www.fxguide.com/featured/brick-by-brick-how-animal-logic-crafted-the-lego-movie/

There are loads of people on YouTube who make Lego films some great, some good and some rubbish. Just spend some time researching it all.